# How to upload a video to YouTube in Android?

Tags: android, video, youtube-api

I want to upload a video file from my Android application. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

by using **ytd-android**
[here](http://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/) is demo project available

you can upload youtube video.

If you have fix username and password then
see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10432215/1289716)

have a niec  developing.....