# Automatically Select youtube using intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube

I want to upload video on you-tube and i am uploading video using this code but the problem is that whenever i click the button from my app then i have to select you-tube from list view of email,Bluetooth,you-tube,etc..

So i want the permanent solution for this that whenever i click a button from my app it automatically moves to you-tube without showing list view.

So, this is my code which i used to upload video over you-tube.

```
              **ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
                content.put(Video.VideoColumns.TITLE, "My Test");
                content.put(Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
                content.put(Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
                content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, outputFile);
                ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
                Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,content);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("video/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share using"));**
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if this works. Can you try intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");

Comment: enigma, this one is not working.

Comment: Then I'm not sure if there's any way to do it using Intents. You must use the Youtube API as discussed here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712661/how-to-upload-a-video-to-youtube-in-android

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Intent.ACTION\_SEND Youtube](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006012/android-intent-action-send-youtube)

Answer (score 0):

This might help you,

```
String url = "http://youtu.be/mo1DmO9JH3Y"; // Your Url here..
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://"+url));  
activity.startActivity(intent);
```