# upload video to youtube from android using google-api-java-client 1.14.1 or ytd-android-0.2

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-api-java-client

Further to my earlier question which is not answered

[using youtube data in android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324240/using-youtube-data-in-android-project)

my goal is to upload YouTube video, and after get the URL, then do a search by key developer.

I spent three days and not found yet aworking code for Android.

i try this code that Initially appears to be superior :

[How to upload a video to YouTube in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712661/how-to-upload-a-video-to-youtube-in-android)

that link to this file

https://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/downloads/list

but i recive toast that write :

"Request made to myytdDomain failed.  Please make sure you have the correct domain"

i chack cuple time, but myytdDomain is right...

and in locate error

```
05-02 20:01:37.889: E/Adreno200-ES20(128): <qgl2DrvAPI_glUseProgram:1318>: **** 293: glUseProgram(6)
05-02 20:01:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(6775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 20:01:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(6775): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android/android.accounts.GrantCredentialsPermissionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 20:01:38.279: E/AndroidRuntime(6775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
```

if someone work recently with this code and it's work or not I'm interested to hear about it...

after this i find this article :

http://diablo-urban-o.com/post/9880535810/uploading-videos-to-youtube-from-android

i try to use it but in fifth Paragraph they order to dawnload Google API Client Library for Java, version 1.14.1-beta

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/list

" once you uncompress it you’ll find several jar files but for the youtube functionality we’ll need google-api-client-xxx and google-api-client-googleapis and two more dependencies guava-r09 and jackson-core-asl (you can follow here - it’s in spanish), so all you have to do is to add these libraries to the project build path."

the problem is that whan i unzip this file i discover that there is no google-api-client-xxx jar file and google-api-client-googleapis jar

After I gave up seeking back here to ask if anyone has a way, please write down detailed answer

Comment: Feel free to go through my example open source project, doing this in an IntentService.
https://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of detailed samples for using the Youtube API with the Google API Java Client here:

https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/#git%2Fsamples%2Fjava

In addition, the ZIP for the Google API Java Client certainly does have the jars you're looking for. In the root of the zip there are two directories, "libs" and "libs-sources" (the second which also contains source code, which can be useful for debugging). Note that there is no guava jar anymore as the dependency on guava was removed.