# code for upload video to youtube without using intent

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-api-java-client

my goal is to upload YouTube video, and after get the URL, then do a search by key developer.

someone have a code or example of upload video to youtube without using intent
and tell us which jar files he attached ?

I try for a week and not success, none of my questions about uploading video to YouTube  answered

my Q : 
[upload video to youtube from android using google-api-java-client 1.14.1 or ytd-android-0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345334/upload-video-to-youtube-from-android-using-google-api-java-client-1-14-1-or-ytd)

[using youtube data in android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324240/using-youtube-data-in-android-project)

Comment: Feel free to go through my example open source project, doing this in an IntentService.
https://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are official samples of the Youtube API being accessed with the Google API Java Client here:

https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/#git%2Fsamples%2Fjava

There is an UploadVideo sample, and a Search sample, as well as a number of others.

In addition, there are many other samples for the Google API Java Client here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/?repo=samples

A good one to check out for help with using the library in and Android application is the [tasks-android-sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/tasks-android-sample/instructions.html).  There currently are no specific youtube-android samples, but you should be able to take the ideas from the both and combine them.

As an aside in case it helps: there's plenty of documentation about the API [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) and you can interact with the API in your browser with the API's Explorer [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/youtube/youtube/v3/).

Comment: in the first link I see example in java for upload a video on YouTube but the problem is that I do not know how I can make it use for Android,  I can not run this on my device ... Sorry but I'm pretty new ...